# Sort struct printed on label in alphabetical order

Tags: ios, swift, struct, swift4

My struct is printed in the order of time added right now. What I would like to do is get the string part printed in alphabetical order.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var c: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var a: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    var contacts = [Person]()

    @IBAction func press(_ sender: Any) {
        contacts.append(Person(name: a.text!, phone: Int(c.text!)!))
        label.text = contacts.count == 0 ? "No people to contact" : contacts.map { $0.description }.joined(separator: "\n")
    }
}

struct Person {
    var name: String
    var phone: Int
}

extension Person: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "\(name),\(phone)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `sorted` with a closure that orders the `name` property of the `Person` struct.

```
let sortedContacts = contacts.sorted { $0.name < $1.name }
```

Comment: How would I sort my struct by alphabetical order and decending order int so. a, 1; a:4,: a,6. I have tried  {     $0.name < $1.name && $1.phone > $0.phone } but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
(contacts.sorted {$0.description < $1.description}).map {$0.description}.joined(separator: "\n")
```